# SQL converting float to varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've 2 columns which I want to use a condition on. But I get this error message and my query is correct I'll come to that soon.

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type varchar to float.

So this is the problem, I have a temp-table in which ID-number looks like this 9001011234 we can call it A, in the other one that I want to check with it looks like this 900101-1234 and this one for B this is the swedish format for Id-numbers.

So in my condition I want to check this to get the right amount and the correct result.

```
where A = B
```

The rest of the query is fine, when I remove this condition it gives me a result. It's just this one bit that is incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a `VARCHAR` format that can't be trivially transformed to a number. I'd use `REPLACE(b,'-','') = a` to fix the format, and let SQL Server take care of the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Say:

```
where A = CAST(REPLACE(B, '-', '') AS float)
```

Comment: Thank you! I to am a beemer guy ;)

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to compare values that are not the same datatype. eg Where 'one' = 1

You will need to convert one of the values to the same datatype as the other.

Comment: You cant convert when one of them is numeric and the other one float. The other thing is I will get the wrong result set since one of them have the format 900101-1234 and the other one 9010011234